# Delphi XE3 Getting XML content from a web page

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-xe3, idhttp

I am trying to get xml content from a web page on Delphi XE3, coding on firemonkey for the Mac OS X platform. On Windows I can just use the Filename property on a TXMLDocument, but it seems on Firemonkey for Mac this is disabled.

The URL I am trying to read: http://thetvdb.com/api/GetSeries.php?seriesname=New Girl

If I plug it into a browser I get the URL as: http://thetvdb.com/api/GetSeries.php?seriesname=New%20Girl, and the page contains xml content I am trying to access.

I have been trying to use IdHTTP.Get to get the content into a memory stream, and it works fine if the page has an .XML file target, but with the above URL it does not work. Even if I use the second altered  url it just returns exceptions.

Any ideas would be really appreciated.

Comment: The URL must be encoded, so using the second form is correct. What is the exception you get? Please show some code. On the TXMLDocument component, the DOMVendor should be `ADOM XML` not `MSXML`, and you must remove `Xml.Win.msxmldom` from the Uses clause.

Comment: Setting the `TXMLDocument.FileName` to a URL is not guaranteed to work, it is very vendor-specific. So using `TIdHTTP` is a wise choice. Using the second URL works fine for me when I try it, I do get the expected XML: `IdHTTP.Get('http://thetvdb.com/api/GetSeries.php?seriesname=New%20Girl', Stream);`